# Selecting and processing INI file sections that start with a given string

Tags: c++, c++builder

I am reading sections from Ini file with the use of inbuilt function ReadSections(). so for that i have to pass section name as argument but now i want to read all sections which starts from ADD.EXE , how can i do that? there will be multiple sections like ADD.EXE_NEW, ADD.EXE_OLD, ADD.EXE_First, SEC.EXE, THIRD.EXE so i just wan to read those sections whose name starts with ADD.EXE

```
  unique_ptr<TDataIniFile> UserIni(new TDataIniFile(File));

  if (UserIni->ReadSections("ADD.EXE")
```

Comment: "IniFile" is not part of the c++ standard. Please edit your question with a link to (or the actual definition of) that class.

Comment: Don't focus on IniFile, it's just class name .  try to understand the problem.
The main problem here i am facing is in the below line 
if (UserIni->ReadSections("ADD.EXE")
Where i want all sections which starts from "ADD.EXE"

I know in Unix we have simple * asterisk for whatever appended we can easily find out but in C++ how to do i am not aware. if you know then let us know.

Comment: That question can only be answered by inspecting the interface of that IniFile (or TDataIniFile, apparently) class. Which is why I am asking to see the full class declaration. If there is something like "GetAllSections" or an iterator over all sections, you can use a trivial loop and string matching.

Comment: Okay, but as such there is no functions like GetAllSections, yes we can use ReadSections() where can use trivial loop and string matching.
Can you tell me how can we do that?

Comment: For the third time now, I cannot do that without knowing the actual API so I know what `GetAllSections` returns!

Comment: @Botje  Ok, please suggest code with GetAllSections().

Comment: I can't, because that is a made up function. Since you cannot or will not share the API with us I wish you the best of luck finding a solution by yourself.

Comment: @Botje [`TCustomIniFile.ReadSections()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.IniFiles.TCustomIniFile.ReadSections)

Answer (score 1):

[`ReadSections()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IniFiles.TCustomIniFile.ReadSections) takes a `TStrings*` pointer to a string list object that you create and it will then fill in with section names from the INI, eg:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<TStringList> sections(new TStringList);
std::unique_ptr<TDataIniFile> UserIni(new TDataIniFile(File));
UserIni->ReadSections(sections.get());
```

You can then enumerate through that string list as needed, eg:

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < sections->Count; ++i)
{
    String section = sections->Strings[i];
    if (StartsText(_D("ADD.EXE"), section))
    {
        // read values for section from UserIni as needed...
    }
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
// standard range-for doesn't work with TStringList, but
// std::for_each() does via iterators from non-member
// begin()/end() functions found via ADL...

//for(String section : *sections)
std::for_each(begin(sections.get()), end(sections.get()),
    [&](const String &section)
    {
        if (StartsText(_D("ADD.EXE"), section))
        {
            // read values for section from UserIni as needed...
        }
    }
);
```